# Polymer - how to get the ID from paper-Input?

Tags: dart, polymer

[Dart+Polymer]

Hello,

I have PaperInput elements in a Polymer dom-repeat template. So, there are several, so on the @Listen I try to get the id, but it only retrieves id="**labelAndInputContainer**" (no matter what I do in the template).

Is there some trick to this? I've tried "everything" - over the past half a day!

Here is my HTML:

```
        <template is="dom-repeat" items={{rgetThem}}>
            <paper-card heading={{yyyy(item)}} >
                <div class="card-content"  >
                    <p style="color:red">ID:{{getID(item)}}</p>
                        <paper-input on-change="onchangepassword"
                                     label='Password'
                                     id={{getID(item)}}
                                     floatingLabel>
                        </paper-input>
                </div>
```

And the listener:

```
@Listen ('onchangepassword')
  void onchangepassword(Event custEvent, var t) {
    IronInput PI=custEvent.target;
    Element yy=PI.parent;
    String id=yy.id;
  }
```

Any suggestions MOST welcome.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#handling-events. Event.model.item.id

Comment: That might be what Lymp is after, but my impression was Lymp was asking a question of a way of getting the id of the PaperInput from which the event is raised.  Never mind :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Element yy=PI.parent.closest('paper-input');
```

The problem you're facing is paper-element encapsulates an iron-input element wrapped in div elements.  Finding the closest paper-input will find the paper-input which the iron-input is encapsulated in, since that's the nearest one.  I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this works for me.  In fact you could just do

```
Element yy=PI.closest('paper-input');
```

which will work just as well.

UPDATE:

Upon seeing the comment about dom-repeat event models, it occurs to me you may want a more Polymer Dart specific documentation link.

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/data-binding-helper-elements#handling-events-in-dom-repeat-templates

As was suggested

```
model.item.id
```

And I'm not going to take credit for the updated part of my answer except the Dart specific link.